# Using character-map in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I am trying to use an xsl document with a character-map to replace certain special characters in my xml file; here is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="lesson12.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE Groceries>
    <Groceries xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="lesson12.xsd">
     <Item><Name>Wasabi &#38; Soy Sauce Almonds</Name></Item>
     <Item><Name>Peanut Butter &#38; Jelly Spread</Name></Item>
     <Item><Name>Pork &#38; Beans</Name></Item>
     <Item><Name>Coca Cola&#174;</Name></Item>
     <Item><Name>Sprite&#174;</Name></Item>
     <Item><Name>Dr. Pepper&#174;</Name></Item>
     </Groceries>
```

Here is my schema:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:token" />
     </xs:schema>
```

Here is my xsl:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     version="2.0">

     <xsl:output method="html" use-character-maps="my_char_map" />

     <xsl:character-map name="my_char_map">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#38;" string="and"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="&#174;" string="TM"/>
     </xsl:character-map>

     <xsl:template match="/"> 

     <h3>Groceries</h3>
     <xsl:for-each select="/Groceries/Item/Name">
     <ul>
     <li>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </li>
     </ul>
     </xsl:for-each>

     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am still learning about xml, not sure if my xsl:output needs to be corrected, or if it something else.

Thanks!
AC

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using [Saxon CE](http://saxonica.com/html/ce/download.html), your browser is only going to handle XSLT 1, which does not support character-map.

(And, your schema doesn't define `<Groceries>` or `<Item>`, but that doesn't matter, since the browser won't look at it either. But an XSLT 2 parser in schema-aware mode might complain...)

Comment: Thanks!  I actually do need to run it through Saxon - it is now working!